# Jupyter Notebook is not connecting with Kernel

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

this is a problem on 7th March 2019 and jupyter-notebook was working fine till 6th March 2019.

Today it is showing

**A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.**

I tried to uninstall tornado but it showed that it tornado was not installed.

I then installed tornado 5.1.1 which went well but still the problem exists.

My Ubuntu is 16.04 LTS and system is Intel® Core™ i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4.

I had done sudo apt-get install update and sudo apt-get upgrade command yesterday. I now removed the updates which were done yeaterday but still problem persists.

The error coming in the terminal window is :

```
dstlab2@dstlab2-Veriton-M200-H81:~$ jupyter-notebook[I 09:26:02.991 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /run/user/1000/jupyter/notebook_cookie_secret
[I 09:26:04.290 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 09:26:04.290 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/dstlab2/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 09:26:04.293 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/dstlab2
[I 09:26:04.293 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 09:26:04.293 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=a607d9176951f9f7c52829af223e2de939881f925a4f0099
[I 09:26:04.293 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:26:04.354 NotebookApp] 

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=a607d9176951f9f7c52829af223e2de939881f925a4f0099
[I 09:26:09.924 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from 127.0.0.1
[I 09:26:31.426 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 5c1a7abe-8a46-4774-b878-2f93bd60714e
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/dstlab2/code.py", line 36
    'Swig::DirectorMethodException'
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 09:26:34.345 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/dstlab2/code.py", line 36
    'Swig::DirectorMethodException'
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 09:26:37.353 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (2/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/dstlab2/code.py", line 36
    'Swig::DirectorMethodException'
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 09:26:40.362 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (3/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/dstlab2/code.py", line 36
    'Swig::DirectorMethodException'
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[I 09:26:43.374 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (4/5), new random ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/home/dstlab2/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/home/dstlab2/code.py", line 36
    'Swig::DirectorMethodException'
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
[W 09:26:46.387 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 09:26:46.388 NotebookApp] Kernel 5c1a7abe-8a46-4774-b878-2f93bd60714e died, removing from map.
[W 09:26:52.810 NotebookApp] Replacing stale connection: 5c1a7abe-8a46-4774-b878-2f93bd60714e:cc118d38384143ce89970738bb0b0708
```

Comment: I saw post saying Downgrading tornado to 4.5.3 fixed my problem.

**with pip - sudo python3.6 -m pip install tornado==4.5.3**

**with conda - conda install tornado==4.5.3** but still my problem is not solved

Comment: check whether python version installed is 3.6 or 3.7?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got it running. It was a lack of understanding on my side: Tensorflow and Jupyter are running in a Docker container anf this container hosted Tornado 6 which causes issues. I had to replace the tornado version 6 by Tornado V5.1.1 inside this container not on normal desktop (which was my first attempt wondering that I didn't find a Tornado installation at all). My fault as I am a newbie in Docker technology - just followed an installation tutorial and started to understand the background later.

pip uninstall tornado==6.0.1
pip install tornado==5.1.1

Comment: could you share the tutorial